# Javascript Variables Become Undefined After Making main.js into Module and Importing from Another .js File

Tags: javascript, html, import, module

I'm trying to have a variable be stated and exported from a .js file, imported to another .js file, and have this latter one be called as a module source to an HTML page. I'm having a console log the value of the variable in order to see if it's a defined variable within the .html page. Whenever I do this, the console gives me an error saying that the variable is undefined. The following code is what I'm using. I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Live Server for JS.

export.js

```
export let MainNumber = 128;
```

main.js

```
import { MainNumber } from "./export.js";
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            console.log(MainNumber);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: MainNumber is not defined
 http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:10

I expected the console to print 128. However, it seems to me that making main.js into a module is making MainNumber become undefined in index.html for some reason. If I state MainNumber directly into main.js, without importing it from another .js file, it prints just fine with no errors. For example, the code below works correctly.

main.js

```
let MainNumber=128;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            console.log(MainNumber);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

console prints:
128

How can I make my imported variables not be undefined in HTML? What is the reason for this last example of code to work just fine but the not the one before, that depends on importing it from elsewhere and thus requiring main.js to be defined as a module? Thanks in advance. I have looked into this a lot but I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Yes, variables in modules are not accessible from outside if they are not exported and then imported

Comment: Is there any way that I can make this variable accessible within my .html file? If not with a module, what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: `window.MainNumber = MainNumber` in main.js

Comment: I have made this change to main.js, but the same error message is still shown to me in the console when running the script. Could you give me an example of how window could make the module variable accessible in .html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do have a look at 2 events before you check out 1 of many possible solutions. When the browser receives HTML content, it starts parsing from top to bottom. 2 events are important:

- `DOMContentLoaded` => regular scripts
- `Load` => async scripts and modules

Your regular scripts will fire before asynchoronous stuff is done, that's why you cannot receive the value. There is so many solutions to what you want, one of them is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <script>
            window._prom = new Promise(r => window._r = r);
        </script>
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            window._prom.then(result => console.log("MainNumber is", result));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

inside your head, put a regular script before everything else just to register a `Promise` and get its resolver (`_r`) attached to window. Now any `async` script or scripts with `type=module` will see what you atttached to window:

```js
import { MainNumber } from "./export.js";
window._r(MainNumber);
```

Inside `main.js`, use the resolver to pass your value.

Finally in the other regular scripts downstream, read the value from the `Promise`:

`window._prom.then(result => console.log("MainNumber is", result));`

If you do not like `then`, use an async iife:

```js
(async()=>{
 const MainNumber = await window._prom;
 //do something
})()
```

This is just to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have understood what's going on and what to look into.